# Django - Restricting User Access to the Admin Site

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I am trying to create an app for tracking team rosters that is based in the django admin (ie localhost/admin).

I would like to set it up so that I can assign certain teams to certain users, such that when they log in to the admin site, they can only see and edit the teams they have been assigned to.

I would like a user with superadmin status to be able to add and remove user access to various teams through the admin site, without having to modify the underlying code each time a new user or team is added. Is there a way to do this?

```
class Team(models.Model):
    team_name = ...
    # Whatever other attributes.

class Player(models.Model):
    first_name = ...
    last_name = ...
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team)
    # Whatever stats you want to keep on the players
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can dynamically change the query set used by the admin; you could do this to only show teams that are associated with the logged-in user.

```
class TeamModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_queryset(request):
         return Team.objects.filter(...)
```

Comment: But how do I associate a team with a user?

Comment: It depends on whether a team has one associated user or whether a team has many associated users; this might be a "ForeignKey" field (for m2o) or a "ManyToManyField" pointing to the user class. There's good documentation in the Django docs on creating both of those at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/.